# Why is Linear Discriminant Analysis called Linear Discriminant Analysis?

Tags: machine-learning, terminology, linear, discriminant-analysis

If this is the wrong place to put this question please let me know and I will be happy to switch it to the correct place - I just assumed this would be the correct place.

I've Googled around and I can't seem to find an answer. Firstly - a lot of places call Linear Discriminant Analysis a classification method - from my understanding, while it's used to help classification, **it doesn't directly classify anything**. It's simply a dimension reduction technique - so why do people call it a classification method? It's like me creating a program that simply adds two numbers together and calling it an "integer multiplication program" - like sure, it can be used for that, but doesn't do it directly. You still have to do extra work to get the desired result.

Secondly, the name has "Discriminant" in it - but according to other sources (and it makes sense) - it's actually a Generative model. Why is it named this way? Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: A classifier isn’t just a classifier. There’s this false western notion that things are all disconnected. Clustering, classification, dimensionality reduction, and regression are all part of the same something. When you do one of them you are implicitly doing one or more of the others. When you are making a line they can separate two classes, a linear discriminator, you are implicitly clustering, you are implicitly regressing. Some axes are more important than others. Lots of the early work involved straight lines. Linear can also mean least squares fits do the job. So that expands the domain.

Comment: @EngrStudent I see, so you are saying that dimension reduction is, in some way, the same as solving a classification problem? If so, how would I go from performing LDA to doing classification without using another method?

Comment: I might refer you to some of my answers here on LDA. (And of course, to answers of other participants.) LDA is a specific case of _linear model_ including, among other, linear regression and linear canonical analysis. It is therefore linear as dim. reductor. In _another_ sense, LDA is also linear as a linear-boundary classifier.

Comment: @ttnphns but then how would you actually go about using LDA to classify things? From my understanding, LDA is just about finding a vector ${\boldsymbol{w}}$ such that when you project your data along this vector, the result is nice class separation. But as far as I am aware, **this is all LDA is**. If you want to then classify points, you have to do extra things, right? So why is LDA called a classifier if you have to do extra steps?

Comment: This is exactly what I am addressing in my answers. The second, classification phase of LDA is the gaussian classifier.

Comment: @ttnphns I see, so you are saying that actually using Bayes theorem to find the discriminant is actually apart of LDA?